# Largest prime factor algorithm returning out of memory error

Tags: julia

I'm trying to learn Julia via project Euler. And for the largest prime factor problem I ran into an issue with out of memory error and I don't understand why.

I have tried the same solution in Python and had no issues.

```
function Primes(n)
    numbers = Set{Int64}(2:n)
    primes = Int64[]
    while length(numbers)!=0
        p = pop!(numbers,minimum(numbers))
        push!(primes,p)
        if length(numbers)!=0
            numbers = setdiff(numbers,Set{Int64}(2*p:p:maximum(numbers)))
        end
    end
    return primes
end

function LPF(n)
    primes = Primes(n//2)
    for p in primes
        if n%p==0
            return p
        end
    end
end

LPF(600851475143)
```

this is my error message:

```
OutOfMemoryError()

Stacktrace:
 [1] _growend! at .\array.jl:811 [inlined]
 [2] resize! at .\array.jl:1003 [inlined]
 [3] rehash!(::Dict{Int64,Nothing}, ::Int64) at .\dict.jl:183
 [4] sizehint! at .\dict.jl:242 [inlined]
 [5] sizehint! at .\set.jl:64 [inlined]
 [6] union!(::Set{Int64}, ::UnitRange{Rational{Int64}}) at .\abstractset.jl:79
 [7] Type at .\set.jl:10 [inlined]
 [8] Primes(::Rational{Int64}) at .\In[14]:2
 [9] LPF(::Int64) at .\In[24]:2
 [10] top-level scope at In[25]:1
```

Comment: you are trying to create a set containing approximately `300*10^9` entries - it is rather unlikely that you have that much memory. It is interesting that Python is able to allocate that much memory (have you also used the same `n` and approach?).

Comment: I would assume that even you will not be able to store the the `primes` vector in RAM as it would have to have over `11_000_000_000` entries.

Comment: What's the proper way to generate primes? I know i can just do it with a package but it's just bugging me since I clearly remember solving this problem in python before

Comment: Well - the problem does not ask you to generate primes but to find a factorization of `n`. However, if you want to try list all primes first note that `n` cannot be divisible by a prime larger than `isqrt(n)`. The example code to generate small primes is given in my tutorial http://bogumilkaminski.pl/files/julia_express.pdf.

Comment: Thank you. I'll definitely be reading through your tutorial, for more than just the primes algorithm! I need all the help I can get with Julia :P

Comment: Actually one more thing, if the primes vector was the issues, what if i just build a generator instead. I know that julia doesn't have something like the yield function, but do you think that would work? I did try it in python and it still didn't work, but I'm almost certain that's what I had done before.

Comment: Julia has generators, but I guess you meant resumable functions. Here is an example package that gives you this functionality https://github.com/BenLauwens/ResumableFunctions.jl. However, in this problem you do not really need it.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what i meant.